# Validations for Textfields in swift with 0 and empty textfield

Tags: ios, swift, validation, uitextfield

How to validate Textfields with greater than 0 value. i tried all suggestions of stack overflow i failed to validate it. and how to check value of textfield less than or equal to my label value.

```
 let inputStr = totalAmountTextfield.text as? String 
    let inputInt = Int(inputStr!)

    if (inputInt)! < 0 
   {
     let alert = UIAlertView() alert.title = "Message" 
    alert.message = "Enter Valid Amount" 
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Ok") 
    alert.delegate = self alert.show() }
    else{ print("pay pressed")
     razorpay.open(options) } 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are best practices for validating email addresses in Objective-C for iOS 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800123/what-are-best-practices-for-validating-email-addresses-in-objective-c-for-ios-2)

Comment: Show what you have already tried.

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023145/validate-text-fields-swift-3

Comment: let inputStr = totalAmountTextfield.text as? String
        let inputInt = Int(inputStr!)
        if (inputInt)! < 0
        {
            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Message"
            alert.message = "Enter Valid Amount"
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Ok")
            alert.delegate = self
            alert.show()
       
        }else{
            
            print("pay pressed")
                       razorpay.open(options)
        }
    }

Comment: The above code i tried PGDev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple convert your input string to double and check with that

[image]

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController {


        @IBOutlet weak var txt: UITextField!

        @IBAction func onClickSubmit(_ sender: Any)
        {
            let inputStr:String = txt.text ?? ""

            let alert = UIAlertController()
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            if inputStr.isEmpty
            {
                alert.message = "Please Enter Text"
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
            else
            {
                let inputInt = inputStr.integerValue

                if (inputInt)! < 0
                {
                    alert.message = "Enter Valid amount"
                       self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

                }

                else
                {
                    print("Pay to Proceed")
                }
            }

        }

    }

    extension String
    {

        func isNumber() -> Bool{
            let numberCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
            return !self.isEmpty && self.rangeOfCharacter(from:numberCharacters) == nil
        }
        struct NumberFormat
        {
            static let instance = NumberFormatter()
        }
        var integerValue:Int?
        {
            if self.isEmpty
            {
                return 0
            }
            else
            {
                return (NumberFormat.instance.number(from: self)?.intValue) ?? 0
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: at same the time how  to check textfield empty or not

Comment: you can check it before converting, but using above `extension` even if you pass blank string it will return 0. so you show alert

Comment: let inputStr:String = ""
 in this line of code you are comparing with string variable but in my case i am using textfield, how can i use your code.

Comment: i am new to ios thats why little confusion about it.

Comment: let inputInt = (totalAmountTextfield.text as? integerValue)
here i am getting error Use of undeclared type 'integerValue' in second condition can you help me how to fix this issues

Comment: write `(totalAmountTextfield.text as? String).integerValue`

Comment: Value of type 'String?' has no member 'integerValu' i am getting this error

Comment: @kishan write the above code `let inputStr:String = (totalAmountTextfield.text as? String) ?? ""` then use inputStr why are you using totalAmount.text u can simply use inputStr

Comment: i am saying about this let inputInt = inputStr.integerValue

    if (inputInt)! < 0
    {

Comment: ya then what is problem above code is working perfectly

Comment: can you give sample for message validation

Comment: yeah thanks great explination. please send sample code for string validation.